# Recursive macro in scheme causes unexpected loop

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Could someone please explain why does this code cause a loop?

```
(define-macro proc
 (lambda (n)
   `(begin
     (display ,n)
     (set! ,n (+ ,n 1))
     (if (< ,n 10)
         (proc ,n)))))

(let ((x 5))
  (proc x))
```

Comment: It's not even Scheme, `define-macro` is not found in the Report.

Comment: I mean, several schemes 'do' support `define-macro`, although they are generally (very) discouraged: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Defmacros.html. Also Racket has one, although its also highly discouraged: http://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/defmacro.html?q=define-macro#%28form._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fdefmacro..rkt%29._define-macro%29%29

Comment: @LeifAndersen I think bipll hints that `define-macro` is not in any of the reports and thus not really a Scheme form. Most implementations do have macros since it's the only sane way to implement the language, but that is de-facto. As a valid comparison: Would a form only known to work in PyPy really be Python code? I vote for removing both scheme and lisp tag.

Comment: I mean, by that argument, we should also remove the Racket tag. Because that's not really Racket code, nor is it part of the racket ecosystem (besides a compatibility lib). Also, Python's standard is (afaict) the CPython implementation. So no, it wouldn't be python. Scheme doesn't really have a single canonical standard. As seen by the 2017 scheme workshop, the scheme community can't really decide what the RNRS document should actually be.

Comment: One camp claims that it is a standard. But another one simply claims it is just a descriptor of the current state of scheme systems, that most implementations try to use in order to make code portability easier.

Answer (score 0):

You `proc` macro *always* expands into a call to `proc`. If you want to expand conditionally, your test must be done at macroexpansion time (untested):

```
(define-macro proc 
  (lambda (n) 
    `(begin ,(if (< n 10) `(proc ,(+ n 1)) '())))
```

Comment: Which then would require that the value of N is known at macroexpansion of time...

Answer (score 0):

You never stop the macro expansion - macro expansion occurs before evaluation and not "on demand", so you can't use an evaluation-time value for conditional expansion.

In other words,

```
(proc x)
```

expands to

```
(begin
 (display x)
 (set! x (+ x 1))
 (if (< x 10)
     (proc x)))
```

which expands to

```
(begin
 (display x)
 (set! x (+ x 1))
 (if (< x 10)
     (begin
         (display x)
         (set! x (+ x 1))
         (if (< x 10)
             (proc x)))))
```

which expands to

```
(begin
 (display x)
 (set! x (+ x 1))
 (if (< x 10)
     (begin
         (display x)
         (set! x (+ x 1))
         (if (< x 10)
             (begin
                 (display x)
                 (set! x (+ x 1))
                 (if (< x 10)
                 (proc x)))))))
```

and so on, ad infinitum.